# Re-rendering ng-table in an angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

Am facing a rather strange problem with ng-table. Here is an extract of some code in my controller

```
this.category = "Open";
this.category = ["Open", "Accepted", "Rejected"];
this.dataItems = [];

var _this = this;

this.$scope.$watch("vm.category", function(category) {
    _this.dataItems.length = 0; // To clear items already in the array  

    svc.getApplications(category).then(
        function(okResult) {
            angular.copy(okResult.data, _this.dataItems);

            _this.tableParams = new NgTableParams(
            {
                page: 1,
                count: 5,
                sorting: {
                    applicationDate: 'desc'
                }
            },
            {
                total: _this.dataItems.length,
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    var filtered = params.filter() ? _this.$filter('filter')(_this.dataItems, _this.filter) : _this.dataItems;
                    var ordered = params.sorting() ? _this.$filter('orderBy')(filtered, params.orderBy()) : filtered;

                    params.total(ordered.length);
                    if (params.total() < (params.page() - 1) * params.count()) {
                        params.page(1);
                    }

                    $defer.resolve(ordered.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                }
            }
    });
```

Obviously, I have left out quite a chunk of the code for brevity. `$scope`, `$filter`, `NgTableParams` are all being injected

On the UI, I have the a dropdown as follows:

```
<select id="cbCategory" class="form-control" data-ng-model="vm.category" data-ng-options="category for category in vm.categories"></select>
```

and the ng-table as follows:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="tb1" data-ng-table="vm.tableParams">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="item in $data">
            <td data-title="'Email'" data-filter="{ email: 'text' }" data-sortable="'email'">{{item.applicant.email}}</td>
            <!-- more... -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**This is the nature of the problem am facing:** The table renders fine/okay the first time. When I change the selection on the category dropdown, the call to `getApplications` happens and even the line `_this.tableParams = new NgTableParams` is executed (I have debugged through the code to confirm it and the service call executes without an error). However, `getData` somehow doesn't fire so there is no change on the UI. I have used ng-table extensively but this is the first place am having it re-rendered in this manner. What am I missing?
For avoidance of doubt, there is `controllerAs: vm` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the code above wouldn't work, but a little reorganisation of the logic in the controller caused it to work:

```
this.category = "Open";
this.category = ["Open", "Accepted", "Rejected"];
this.dataItems = [];

var _this = this;

_this.tableParams = new NgTableParams(
{
    page: 1,
    count: 5,
    sorting: {
        applicationDate: 'desc'
    }
},
{
    total: _this.dataItems.length,
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        var filtered = params.filter() ? _this.$filter('filter')(_this.dataItems, _this.filter) : _this.dataItems;
        var ordered = params.sorting() ? _this.$filter('orderBy')(filtered, params.orderBy()) : filtered;

        params.total(ordered.length);
        if (params.total() < (params.page() - 1) * params.count()) {
            params.page(1);
        }

        $defer.resolve(ordered.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
}

this.$scope.$watch("vm.category", function(category) {
    _this.dataItems.length = 0; // To clear items already in the array  

    svc.getApplications(category).then(
        function(okResult) {
            angular.copy(okResult.data, _this.dataItems);

            // ADDED THIS...
            if (_this.tableParams) {
                _this.tableParams.reload();
            }
    });
```

Note that I tried putting the `reload()` in several other places but it didn't work